# How do I set a domain name with a port in hosts file?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, ruby-on-rails, hosts

I have Apache and Rails running on my laptop. Apache is running on port 80 and rails 3000.

in my hosts file I have entries like

127.0.0.1 dev.somesite.com

This works well for Apache

How do I add an entry that routes to port 3000?

Something like 127.0.0.1:3000 dev.somerailssite.com ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. The port is not part of name resolution.

Comment: Do you know how would i go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible.  Hosts file lookups resolve between names and IP addresses, without regard to the transport layer; ports are a function of the transport layer.  Refer to the OSI model for more on that.

One thing you could do is use [name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) in apache, and set up a virtual host at dev.somerailssite.com which redirects to dev.somerailssite.com:3000.